# Find the coordinates of the corners of a rotated object in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Suppose I have an image in a fabricjs canvas. I can easily calculate the coordinates of the corners based on the image's `top` & `left` values, and its size.

**How can I do so when the image is rotated by any degree?**

Example:

[image]

EDIT: Preferably without the use of trigonometry, if there is a simpler method implemented in fabricjs itself or somewhere else.

Comment: Calculate the start points, and then use a matrix to compute where they are based on the rotation > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)

Comment: You'll have to use trigonomics. There isn't a built-in method for that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, of course.

We store those coordinates in object's `oCoords`

```
oCoords.tl.x, oCoords.tl.y // top left corner 
oCoords.tr.x, oCoords.tr.y // top right corner
oCoords.bl.x, oCoords.bl.y // bottom left corner
oCoords.br.x, oCoords.br.y // bottom right corner
```

That's what gets set when you call `setCoords` method.

But you probably don't want to mess with those.

Since version ~1.0.4, we have `getBoundingRect` method on all objects, which returns `{ left: ..., top: ..., width: ..., height: ... }`. We already had `getBoundingRectWidth` and `getBoundingRectHeight` before (now deprecated) but `getBoundingRect` is certainly more useful; it allows to read left/top values as well.

You can see it in action at http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle (try rotating objects)

More:
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#oCoords
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#calcCoords

Comment: Thanks - I used oCoords which is perfect. No need for Math.sin! It allowed me to "attach" custom made handles to only two corners of an object, instead of the 9 default ones...

Comment: link is unavailable

Comment: Link is http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle (without a trailing slash)