# How to get the coordinates of the corners of a rotated element?

Tags: rotation, coordinates, element, kineticjs, fabricjs

I am trying to get the corners of a rotated element in kineticjs. I found a similiar thread for fabricjs and would like to know if there is a similar solution for kineticjs.

[Find the coordinates of the corners of a rotated object in fabricjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874631/find-the-coordinates-of-the-corners-of-a-rotated-object-in-fabricjs)

I have a layer with an image in it, the image has a negative offset so the origin point is in the center. The layer gets the rotation.

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({rotationDeg: 45});
var image = new Kinetic.Image({width: 100, height: 100, offsetX: -50, offsetY: -50});
layer.add(Image);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use some trigonometry:

```
function findRotatedCornerXY(rectX,rectY,rectWidth,rectHeight,degreeAngle,
                             originalCornerX,originalCornerY){

    // calc rotation centerpoint
    var cx=rectX+rectWidth/2;
    var cy=rectY+rectHeight/2;

    // calc length from rect center to any rect corner
    var r=Math.sqrt(rectWidth/2*rectWidth/2+rectHeight/2*rectHeight/2);

    // calc unrotated angle from center to corner
    var dx=originalCornerX-cx;
    var dy=originalCornerY-cy;
    var originalAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);

    // calc new angle of rotated corner
    var radianAngle=degreeAngle*Math.PI/180;
    var newAngle=originalAngle+radianAngle;

    // calc XY of rotated corner
    var rx = cx + r * Math.cos(newAngle);
    var ry = cy + r * Math.sin(newAngle);

    // return the results
    return({x:rx,y:ry});
}
```